# Блок-схемы

Tags: javascript, html, css

Необходимо сделать web-версию блок-схемы. Подскажите наиболее хорошее решение, на чистом html,css получается не достаточно функционально. С применением таких плагинов как jsPlumb и подобных, не получается настроить связи, и они вылазят на другие блоки

Answer (score 2):

Это может помочь:

1. Использовать svg. Его можно в html инлайнить.
   Кстати, если схема не меняется, то svg можно сделать в любом векторном редакторе.
2. Использовать shadow dom. Годится только для современных браузеров.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите, что умеет например [D3](http://d3js.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Делайте с помощью Canvas. А связи пересчитывайте только для того блока, который перемещаете. Посмотрите как сделан "дизайнер" в PHPMyAdmin.

Разумеется, каждый блок - это объект своего "класса". Чтобы ьыло проще отслеживать
количество связей

Comment: Блоки не должны перемещаться, видимо и правда всё придется рисовать вручную,